# Babel - can not use async/await and regeneratorRuntime error

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, async-await, babeljs

I am trying to write testing for Vue application by using Vue Test Utils. I have faced the issue "ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined" because of compiling async/await in babel.

Searching online, I installed the following dependencies

**In my "devDependencies"**

```
"@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
"@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.15.0",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
"@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.1.1",
"@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.1.1",
"@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^4.5.13",
"@vue/cli-service": "^3.1.1",
"@vue/test-utils": "^1.2.2",
"babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
"babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
"babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
"babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
"babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^1.0.2",
"babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-regenerator": "^6.26.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
"babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
```

**In my "dependencies"**

```js
"babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
"core-js": "^3.16.3",
```

Also, added the plugins in babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@vue/app', "@babel/preset-env"],
  plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime', "transform-regenerator"],
}
```

But when run a test, it still output the same error about **ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined**. I really like to know what's going on with it...Thanks.

Comment: Why are `plugins` defined explicitly? They are supposed to be handled by presets.

Comment: @EstusFlask Could your suggestion an example? I did not understand. Thanks!

Comment: I can't suggest an example because I don't understand what example you expect. The question is why `plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime', "transform-regenerator"]` line exists in babel.config.js. Was it added by you? It shouldn't be there.